# Ubuntu Server 14.04 using 2 net adaptors in VMWare Workstation

Tags: networking, server, vmware

I am student and we are using VMWare Workstation 10 with Ubuntu 14.04. We, including our teacher, are trying to figure out what is going wonky with our configurations.

In Vmware, the goal is to have one net adaptor in Bridged or NAT (we have tried both methods) to access the schools network for internet and have our second network adaptor in host only with dhcp disabled in the vmeditor for our private networks.

Thusfar, at when we do the original setup, we get it working. However, after a few reboots, no more internet ever though our ifconfig results are showing the right ips. We can regain internet access by doing the following :

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifdown eth1
sudo ifup eth0
```

At this point we can access the internet, however, when we try to bring back up the eth1 adaptor, we get an error saying that eth1 is not configured. This is strange within itself, for the simple fact that eth1 has been configure with a static ip.

Here is the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration:

```
- Primary adaptor internet
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
- Secondary adaptor private network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.90.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.90.0
broadcast 192.168.90.255
- Here we have tried using the servers static ip as well as having it commented off 
gateway 192.168.90.254
- Have also tried thinking it would link to the net adaptor
gateway 192.168.90.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that did not format so good:

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you. When you paste code or contents of a file, highlight the text and hit Ctrl+K to make it look nice. You can also edit your question by clicking the `edit` button right underneath it. Back to your question: the default gateway should be `192.168.90.2`, but you don't really need a default gateway for `eth1` because it's a host-only network, so just remove the `gateway` line. Also, remove `network` and `broadcast`, they're not needed anymore. So you should only have `address` and `netmask` under `eth1`.

Comment: Thank you for the formating Alaa Ali. It is most appreciated. And thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the formatting in the question... But are the lines in /etc/network/interfaces

*Primary adaptor internet*
and 
*Secondary adaptor private network*
 Commented out with '#'?

Here's an example for static:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.110.2.9
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.110.0.0
    broadcast 10.110.255.255
  <snip>
```